# Bash: pyvenv: command not found

Tags: debian, python3, virtualenv

I have Debian 8.5. with a python version 3.4.2 as default. I want to create a virtualenv using the python3 [venv](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/venv.html#venv-def) module. But running `pyvenv` in terminal is unable to find the pyvenv:

```
bash: pyvenv: command not found
```

There is a venv directory in `/usr/lib/python3.4`. Why i am unable to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Debian, the best way to find out how to install the necessary package so that a given command will work is to use `apt-file`, as follows:

```
apt-file search bin/pyvenv
```

This will show that you need to install [`python3-venv`](https://tracker.debian.org/python3-venv):

```
apt-get install python3-venv
```

(as `root`).

In current versions of Debian (at least Debian 11 and later), there is no `pyvenv` or `py3venv` binary; you need to install the package as above and run the module by name:

```
python3 -m venv …
```

Answer (score 1):

Learn Debian!

```
apt-file search pyvenv
```

Comment: on Debian Stretch is `apt search pyvenv`